# Intercepting laravel validation errors in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am currently working on a contact form for my website using angular js front end and using Laravel as a backend api.
This is an example of what I have as a field.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
      <label for="title">Your Name*</label>
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="contact_name" type="text" name="contact_name" placeholder="Your Name*">
      <span ng-if="errors.contact_name[0]" class="alert-danger">@{{ errors.contact_name.toString()}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

This makes a call through my controller.

```
$scope.processForm = function ()
{
    $scope.submissionSuccess = false;
    $scope.errors = null;
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/api/post-form',
        data:{
            _token: $scope._token,
            contact_name:$scope.contact_name,
            contact_email:$scope.contact_email,
            phone:$scope.phone,
            message:$scope.message
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){

        /*CLEAR FORM FIELDS*/
        $scope.submissionSuccess = true;
        $scope.contact_name = '';
        $scope.contact_email = '';
        $scope.phone = '';
        $scope.message = '';

        // SHOW SUCCESS FOR 2 SECONDS.
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.submissionSuccess = false;
        }, 2000);

    }).error(function(error){
        $scope.errors = error.data;
    });
}
```

This is then passed to my laravel controller.
And when I log the data into the console I get.

Object
errors
:
Object
contact_email
:
Array[1]
0
:
"The contact email field is required."
length
:
1
**proto**
:
Array[0]
contact_name
:
Array[1]
0
:
"The contact name field is required."
length
:
1
**proto**
:
Array[0]
message
:
Array[1]
0
:
"The message field is required."

How would I display the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this.

```
<span class="has-error" ng-repeat="error in errors.contact_name">{{ error }}</span>
```

Hope this help.